# jQuery navigation with multiple page-files

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation

I still don't understand how I am supposed to write my pages in a jQuery Mobile middle-complexity project, I mean... here's my hello world page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Applicazione Web jQuery Mobile</title>
<link href="file:///D|/Programmi/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/it_IT/Configuration/Third Party Source Code/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="file:///D|/Programmi/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/it_IT/Configuration/Third Party Source Code/jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file:///D|/Programmi/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/it_IT/Configuration/Third Party Source Code/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Pagina uno</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#page2">Pagina due</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Pagina tre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Pagina quattro</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Piè di pagina</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Pagina due</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Contenuto       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Piè di pagina</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Pagina tre</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Contenuto       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Piè di pagina</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Pagina quattro</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Contenuto       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Piè di pagina</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Nice, isn't it?

My third page (id="page3"), for example, will be huge. Obviously I don't want to write all my pages in a single html file, I will rather have a "page3.html" file.

I don't want to avoid the nice jQuery mobile's ajax navigation feature, so what's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have contents of "page3" in a different html file as

content of Page3.html as:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>             
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" /> 
            <script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                alert('This is Page 3');                
            </script>  

    </head>
    <body>
   <div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Pagina tre</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Contenuto       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Piè di pagina</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then on the main page you can have link for that page3.html as

```
<a href="page3.html" data-role="button"  rel="external">Load Page 3</a>
```

Comment: what does "rel='external'" do exactly? What if I remove it?

Comment: you can read more on jquery mobile docs on linking pages:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

and if you want to know exactly how navigation works in jquery mobile then read http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would AJAX load the content in when requested. That way, you're only loading the resources needed when they're asked for.

If you want, you could pre-load images once the document has loaded etc.